# Bloch functions and covalent bonds in some semiconductors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

In a Group IV semiconductor (like Si, Ge), one atom makes 4 covalent bonds with its neighboring atoms. They create in this way the so-called a tetrahedral bond (that of the diamond structure). Each 2 atoms are bound via 2 electrons with opposite spins. These bonding electrons exist in the valence band, they are localized (?). However, the states in a **band** in a solid are described by the delocalised, periodic Bloch states; the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian operator for each pair of values $n$ and $k$.

How do these two scenes (covalent bonds) and (bands of Bloch states) not conflict? Do Bloch states also describe these covalent bond electrons? In other words, could Bloch states be "localized"?

*References are very appreciated.*

**Update and answer:**

The covalent band model I first learned in chemistry uses the bond model. In this model each two atoms in a molecule, like $\text{CH}_4$, are bond covalently via 2 electron. In this model the electrons are more or less localized between the atoms in the molecule. In other words, the electron density is high between the atoms. This model is easily understood in molecules. *However*, in band theory of solids, electrons are described by Bloch states. Bloch states form bands. Electrons in this model are not localized in any way. So how would a covalent band be understood? The only way to understand the covalent bond in the case mentioned for semiconductors above, is that, again, electron density is given by

$$\rho(\mathbf{r})=\sum_n\int_\text{1.BZ}\psi_{nk}^*(\mathbf{r})~\psi_{nk}(\mathbf{r})~d^3k,$$

where $n$ is over all occupied bands.
This spatial residence density is just largest between the neighboring atoms.

Comment: Who says the valence electrons are localized? It is hard to provide a reference to a statement that is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the way bonding and energy levels in semiconductors are covered in, shall we say, more electrical engineering focused classes is hand waving at best, and usually detrimental to actual understanding. The pretty pictures of energy level splittings and covalent bonds tend to be rooted in intro chemistry, and have nothing to do with solid state physics. Sure, they don't want to teach a course in solid state physics...

OK, so what does the band structure of silicon look like? Going back to a very nice 1966 [Physical Review](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.142.530) paper by Manuel Cardona and Fred Pollak, the calculated band structure of silicon is:

[image: Si band structure from k.p]

The bottom three lines are the top valence bands, with the top two of them the light hole and heavy hole bands. All the higher bands are conduction band states.

Note that, for holes to move in the valence band, as required for semiconductor device operation, the valence bands must be delocalized states.

Comment: Thanks. I've also just added an update and an answer to the question above. It goes with this bond model/band theory thing too. In the band theory in solids, it's just that electron density is highest between neighboring atoms.